# timedelta object to float

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Hello any ideas how can convert timedelta object to float in pandas it needs to generalize based on minutes or hours i.e
00:06:46.221000 to 6.46 minutes or
01:06:76.341000 to 66.76 minutes

thanks

Comment: Same idea as the duplicate but with minutes, divide by a minute instead of an hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python2.7/3.2 or higher, you can use the following method (where time_delta_obj is your timedelta object):

```
time_minutes = time_delta_obj.total_seconds()/60.0
```

In Python 3.2 or higher, you could simply use this:

```
time_minutes = time_delta_obj/datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

See [Python 3.2 - datetime and time](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#datetime-and-time) and [timedelta.total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) for more information.

To apply this to a pandas dataframe, use apply():

```
def convert_to_minutes(time_delta_obj):
    return time_delta_obj.total_seconds()/60.0
```

or

```
def convert_to_minutes(time_delta_obj):
    return time_delta_obj/datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Then for the column named 'time_diff' of the df use this:

```
df['time_diff'] = df['time_diff'].apply(convert_to_minutes)
```

Comment: thanks how do you apply this to a pandas series timedelta obj

Comment: @goerge: you divide it by a `Timedelta(minutes=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just divide your `Series` with a `Timedelta(minutes=1)`. Indeed:

```
>>> df
              col
0 00:06:46.221000
1 00:03:12.456000
2 00:02:07.123456
>>> df['col'] / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
0    6.770350
1    3.207600
2    2.118724
Name: col, dtype: float64
```